# Could not find @PathVariable [pathVars] in @RequestMapping Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am just a newbie to the spring MVC following is my code,When i try to go to `bye` i get following error

```
Could not find @PathVariable [pathVars] in @RequestMapping Spring MVC
```

Following is my code

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/runThis/{bye}/{hye}")
    public ModelAndView printBye(@PathVariable Map<String,String> pathVars) {
        String Bye =  pathVars.get("bye");
        String Hye =  pathVars.get("hye");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "you are"+Bye+ "AND Here COmes" +Hye+"!");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**EDIT Full Stack.**

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.springapp.mvc.HelloController.printBye(java.util.Map)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [pathVars] in @RequestMapping

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.springapp.mvc.HelloController.printBye(java.util.Map)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [pathVars] in @RequestMapping
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

root cause

org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.springapp.mvc.HelloController.printBye(java.util.Map)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [pathVars] in @RequestMapping
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [pathVars] in @RequestMapping
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.resolvePathVariable(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:859)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolvePathVariable(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:359)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:170)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.43 logs.
```

Comment: What do you think `@PathVariable` does?

Comment: i assume path Variable is used to map the request to the respected Action. I know my `pathVars` are empty at the moment but even if i make some mapper for them i still get same error.

Comment: Don't assume. Read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:Please Check the code i have made a small modification i still get the same error, Please help me here.

Comment: Please give us the full stack trace.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I have provided the full stack please take a look

Comment: You are using the wrong infrastructure components. I suspect you either are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven />` or `@EnableWebMvc` when using java config. Looks like you are using the `DispatcherServlet` defaults which uses the old infrastructure `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` instead of the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` which has support for this.

Answer (score 7):

you need `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in your dispatcher-servlet config xml

or in the later version of spring use

`@EnableWebMvc` annotation in your spring config class

and please understand @EnableWebMvc is made to replace the mvc:annotation-driven

and making sure the xmlns are correct in your

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this in your code:

```
public ModelAndView printBye(@PathVariable Map<String,String> pathVars) {
```

Change it to this:

```
public ModelAndView printBye(@RequestParam Map<String,String> pathVars) {
```

This is because @RequestParam is used to deal with getting a Map object passed into the parameter while @PathVariable is used to deal with individual items getting passed into the paramter. Here is an example of @PathVariable:

```
public ModelAndView printBye(@PathVariable("bye") String Bye, @PathVariable("hye") String Hye) {
```

Answer (score 0):

With your request mapping you indicate that your URL has a fixed part `/runThis/` and two variable parts `{bye}` and `{hye}` and that you want them to be mapped to two parameters of your method (with matching names as you don't indicate anything else).

But in your method you declare a single parameter named `pathVars`. So you have a mismatch in the names, types and number of parameters. That's what Spring MVC complains about.

So what you want is:

```
@RequestMapping("/runThis/{bye}/{hye}")
public ModelAndView printBye(@PathVariable String bye, @PathVariable String hye) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("message", "you are" + bye + "AND Here COmes" + hye + "!");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

It's even simpler and more type safe than your code. And please read the documentation. This is a very basic example.

Comment: _If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>` or `MultiValueMap<String, String>` then the map is populated with all path variable names and values._

Comment: Thanks for quick response mate, i am a total newbie here, what i wanna ask is that i am looking in a tutorial which says. that  `@PathVariable Map<String,String> pathVars` can handle parametrized URI request. So i think you missed what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I know you can assign request parameters and HTTP headers to a map. Does it really work for path variables as well? Do you have a reference to the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I was quoting from the javadoc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html). The documentation also mentions it [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates).

Answer (score 0):

in some cases if the jspPageName in the ModelAndView(jspPageName) statement

pointing to the page which doesn't exists, you will get the same error

note I use Spring mvc 4.2.4 and JDK 8