# Spring MVC- Storing and Retrieving @PathVariable Map<String, String>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have taken 2 PathVariable, and instead of taking these separately i want to store these 2 PathVariables in to a Map and want to retrieve it from the Map.

In Spring MVC 3.1.0 here is the my Controller class method:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value="/{countryName}/{userName}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPathVar(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVars, Model model) {

    String name = pathVars.get("userName");
    String country = pathVars.get("countryName");

    model.addAttribute("msg", "Welcome " + name+ " to Spring MVC & You are from" + country);
    return "home";
}
```

> My Request URL is :
>   http://localhost:3030/spring_mvc_demo/welcome/India/ashrumochan123

But when giving request using this url, i am getting HTTP Status 400 -

Description: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

When i am taking these Path Variables separately then it is working fine.
Here is the code -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{countryName}/{userName}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String goHome(@PathVariable("countryName") String countryName,
            @PathVariable("userName") String userName, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("msg", "Welcome " + userName
                + " to Spring MVC& You are from " + countryName);
        return "home";
    }
```

Please tell me whether i am doing anything wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think what you are looking to do is possible.  For starters, you are trying coerce a `String` into a `Map`, which is named inconsistently in your annotation and method signature.  Why not just create the map in the controller method from the two parameters?

Comment: @woemler, thank you for your quick response, but this is possible. I have seen some video demonstration regarding this. But confused about the version of Spring MVC they are using.

Comment: Actually @Ashrumochan was true,the method is correct but something else is wrong, I have tried and it work well for me, can I know what spring version you use?

Comment: From Spring doc:

`If the method parameter is Map<String, String> or MultiValueMap<String, String> then the map is populated with all path variable names and values.

Since:
3.0`

Comment: @FreezY, I am using spring-webmvc: 3.1.1

Comment: I'm using Spring 4.2.5.RELEASE, maybe you should check the client request, If problem still persist, try update your spring .

Comment: @Ashrumochan : PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver is available since 3.2

Comment: Thanks @FreezY, Updated to Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE and now its working fine....

Comment: Welcome, have a nice spring :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver.html), it's been there since version 3.2.

For the `@PathVariable` with `Map<String,String>`, I think you are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` on your Spring servlet configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
...
```

I've found it on  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34485542/823160).

Comment: i am using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`

Comment: Can you provide your web and servlet xml? I couldn't reproduce this problem with only this information

Comment: Thanks @Auro Pimentel, Previously i was using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE & now updated to Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE and now its working fine...