# @PathVariable annotation used on a Map method argument

Tags: spring-mvc

SpringMVC's official doc has the following line:

> When a @PathVariable annotation is used on a Map argument, the map is populated with all URI template variables.

My understanding is that I can get a Map object with all path variables like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/{year}/{month}/{day}")
public String getMap(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVariables) {
    .....;
}
```

But I got error: "Could not find @PathVariable [pathVariables] in @RequestMapping" instead. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Thank Reno for the clue. So the solution is: you need to add "<mvc:annotation-driven/>" in your servlet config xml. If it gives you error: "The prefix 'mvc' for element 'mvc:annotation-driven' is not bound.", then add the following config: xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of `Spring` do you use? `Spring` has supported this feature since [3.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/PathVariableMapMethodArgumentResolver.html).

Comment: I'm using Spring-4.2.6.

Comment: If there is another request pattern which similar to this or not? Or check [Spring MVC- Storing and Retrieving @PathVariable Map<String, String>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905876/spring-mvc-storing-and-retrieving-pathvariable-mapstring-string).

Comment: Nice! I found clue from the link you gave me. And problem solved now!  Thank you very much for your help. : )