# Spring mvc @PathVariable gives 'The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, path-variables

Hi I am new to Spring MVC and trying out some simple examples.

I have created a new Spring mvc maven project in eclipse using the archtype 'spring-mvc-archtype'.

I am trying to hit a url and access the PathVariables using @PathParam in a Map 
 < String, String >

Here is my controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/greet")
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value="/welcome/{countryName}/{userName}")
public ModelAndView test(@PathVariable("userName") String userName, @PathVariable("countryName") String countryName) throws IOException{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");
    mav.addObject("mymessage", "Welcome To "+countryName+" , Spring MVC - "+userName);
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/hi/{cn}/{un}")
public ModelAndView hi(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVars){

    String countryName = pathVars.get("cn");
    String userName = pathVars.get("un");

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("home");
    mav.addObject("mymessage", "Hi "+userName+" in "+ countryName);
    return mav;
}
}
```

And here is the Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.gyanbang.kiran.SpringMvc")
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}   
}
```

So when I run this and hit 
http://localhost:8080/SpringMvc/greet/welcome/India/user1 it works fine and I get the desired result.

But on http://localhost:8080/SpringMvc/greet/hi/India/user1 it gives a 400 error with message 
'**The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**'

I have tried few options and also tried changing the spring-webmvc version to 4.1.6.RELEASE but it gives me 404 in that case.

Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want the variables as a map?

Comment: @geoffreydv no specific reason but I want to try it and see how it works. And besides i find it easy as a concept and the way to implement Path Variables. Thanks

Comment: Solved it: Well it seems I need to update spring-context and spring-test artifact version as 4.3.9.RELEASE and spring-webmvc as 4.1.6.RELEASE. 

After updating version it is working fine with above written code. 

Thanks. :-)

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35905876/spring-mvc-storing-and-retrieving-pathvariable-mapstring-string

Answer (score 1):

`@PathVariable` can use  `Map<String,String>`, you need to use `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` into `ApplicationContaxt.xml`. you can find code below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Answer (score 1):

From very beginning I really wondered why your solution doesn't work.

I've checked path variables collected into map - they work correctly. I think your issue was with dispatcher servlet. You can try configure one or search some existing solutions, I propose to use solution from spring box.

Please check my solution on git. Pay attention on `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
```

...

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
}
```

[**Link to my git project solution**](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/spring-mvc-pathvariable-testing)

There is few row of your code, so should be clear for you. But if something is not clear - do not hesitate and ask in comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Spring docs:

> A @PathVariable argument can be of any simple type such as int, long, Date, etc.

(Although this behaviour can be [customised](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder)).

In addition, your controller specifies a URI with two parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hi/{cn}/{un}")
```

But the controller method only declares one: `@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVars`.

If your goal is (as this suggests: "trying out some simple examples") to prove some front to back calls using Spring MVC then perhaps you should keep things simple at first, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hi/{cn}/{un}")
public ModelAndView hi(@PathVariable String cn, @PathVariable String un){
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable response. But I have already defined  
    
     `@RequestMapping(value="/welcome/{countryName}/{userName}")
        public ModelAndView test(@PathVariable("userName") String 
 userName, @PathVariable("countryName") String countryName) 
         throws IOException{`

in the controller 
But I wanted to try this specific case.

Comment: Ok, well if you want to try passing a Map using PathVariable then you'll need to read up on how Spring supports that. I posted a link in the answer above. However, regardless of whether you are passing a Map or not, if your controller method accepts one PathVariable and your RequestMapping declares two parameter placeholders then you'll get an exception. The root cause of the exception you posted about in your question is a result of: (a) using a Map without telling Spring how to handle a Map and (b) delcaring two parameters placeholders but only defining one PathVariable.