# @Pathvariable Map<String,String> is giving me HTTP Status 500 -

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have written a request handler method in a controller class in Spring MVC. When I'm calling the `http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/hello/santhosh/india` URL, I got a HTTP Status 500 - exception.

This is the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/hello/{userName}/{country}")
public ModelAndView sayHello(@PathVariable Map<String, String> pathVar){
    String name = pathVar.get("userName");
    String country = pathVar.get("country");
    System.out.println("Hello!!" + name + " from " + country);

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
    model.addObject("msg","Hello!!" + name);
    return model;
}
```

This is the exception:

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException:
>   Failed to invoke handler method [public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
>   com.techmahindra.controller.LoginController.sayHello(java.util.Map)];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find
>   @PathVariable [pathVar] in @RequestMapping
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>
> root cause
>
> org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException:
>   Failed to invoke handler method [public
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
>   com.techmahindra.controller.LoginController.sayHello(java.util.Map)];
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find
>   @PathVariable [pathVar] in @RequestMapping
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:185)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>
> root cause
>
> **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable**
>   **[pathVar] in @RequestMapping**
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.resolvePathVariable(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:856)
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolvePathVariable(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:718)
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:367)
>     org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

Comment: Which part of *"Could not find @PathVariable [**`pathVar`**] in @RequestMapping"* is confusing you, when the path `/hello/{userName}/{country}` only defines the variables **`userName`** and **`country`**? Change method to `sayHello(@PathVariable String userName, @PathVariable String country)`.

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? I tested your method in 3.2.11.RELEASE version of Spring project I have and the mapping of path variables into the map worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer from this link. [Could not find @PathVariable [pathVars] in @RequestMapping Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970602/could-not-find-pathvariable-pathvars-in-requestmapping-spring-mvc)

I need to add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in my dispatcher-servlet.xml